# "Error getting stats for file: /usr/share/metricbeat/modules.d/system.yml" when running metricbeat on docker

Tags: docker-compose, elk, metricbeat

I'm trying to run metricbeat in a docker container to monitor a server's CPU/RAM usage and load on Kibana, but when I try to run the command `sudo docker-compose up` I get the following error:

> metricbeat    | 2021-07-28T05:02:22.033Z        ERROR   cfgfile/glob_watcher.go:66      Error getting stats for file: /usr/share/metricbeat/modules.d/system.yml

also Kibana doesn't seem to be able to monitor the info although the container's log in the terminal seems to be legit.

These configurations are running on other servers and they work just fine, but I can't seem to figure out the problem here. Also I have ran `sudo chown -R 1000:1000 configs/` and `sudo chmod -R go-w configs/` in my directory.

This is the system.yml file:

```
- module: system
  metricsets:
    - cpu             # CPU usage
    - load            # CPU load averages
    - memory          # Memory usage
    - network         # Network IO
    - process         # Per process metrics
    - process_summary # Process summary
    - uptime          # System Uptime
    #- socket_summary  # Socket summary
    - core            # Per CPU core usage
    - diskio          # Disk IO
    - filesystem      # File system usage for each mountpoint
    - fsstat          # File system summary metrics
    #- raid           # Raid
    #- socket         # Sockets and connection info (linux only)
    #- service        # systemd service information
  enabled: true
  period: 10s
  processes: ['.*']

  # Configure the mount point of the host’s filesystem for use in monitoring a host from within a container
  system.hostfs: "/hostfs"

  # Configure the metric types that are included by these metricsets.
  cpu.metrics:  ["percentages","normalized_percentages"]  # The other available option is ticks.
  core.metrics: ["percentages"]  # The other available option is ticks.
```

And this is the docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  metricbeat:
    image: ${METRICBEAT_IMAGE}
    container_name: metricbeat
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}        
    volumes:
      - ./configs/metricbeat.docker.yml:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml:ro
      - ./configs/modules.d:/usr/share/metricbeat/modules.d:ro

      # system module
      - /proc:/hostfs/proc:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
      - /:/hostfs:ro
```

I appreciate any help as this has been bugging me for a while, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have same error.
I found `modules.d` 'permission is

```
drw-r--r-x  2 root root 4096 Dec  2 15:17 modules.d
```

So I execute:

```
chmod g+X -R modules.d
```

and restart filebeat .Bingo